# How to compile my one test but all tests written by others

Tags: eclipse, maven

There are many tests in the project. Every time when I use 'mvn clean install', it takes a long time and end up with java heap exception. If I use 'mvn clean install -DskipTest=true', when I run my test, it can't find the test class.
So I wonder if there is a way to compile all source files and only one my test file.

My IDE is Eclipse, I set 'mvn clean install' in eclipse's Maven build, to compile all source files, then 'mvn test-compile -Dtest=MyTest'. But when I debug my test, junit just gives a red, failed result, without any error log.

Comment: Make sure that the project has been imported as a Maven project (the project folder icon should be decorated by a small `M` in the upper right) so that the Java code is compiled incrementally by Eclipse's own Java compiler and you can run your JUnit tests directly and instantly within Eclipse.